# Diffrence between importing an existing project into Eclipse VS adding a dependency

Tags: eclipse

I need you help understanding nub stuff

What is the Difference between

```
1. Importing and existing project into Eclipse 
2. Adding a dependency ?
```

Comment: By "Importing existing project", do you mean importing that project into the workspace, or adding the project as a dependency to another project? By "adding a dependency", do you mean adding a JAR as a dependency to some project?

Comment: Importing existing project - i mean importing that project into the workspace. and what is the meaning of adding the project as a dependency

Comment: Then the "difference" is that those are completely different things. If you import things into the workspace, you can edit them. If you add a dependency, you can use the things defined in that dependency in another project. Also, you can add a project from the workspace as a dependency to another project (after importing it into the workspace).

Comment: thanks - i would mark as correct but i  don't have enought votes

Comment: Since this actually seems to be what you meant, I added a more verbose version as an answer. Hope this makes things clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "difference" is that those two are completely different things.

- If you *import projects into the workspace*, you can edit them. For example, you could create a project with Maven, generate Eclipse project files and then import it into Eclipse, or checkout an existing project from SVN or Git am import that one. You can not edit individual files in Eclipse; everything has to be part of a project.
- If you *add a dependency*, you can use the things defined in that dependency in another project. Usually, that dependency would be a JAR file. You can add individual JAR files manually, or use other Programs like Maven aggregate the dependencies and add them to the project.

Also, you can add a project from the workspace as a dependency to another project (after importing both into the workspace). Compared to adding a JAR file as a dependency, this has the advantage that you can edit the one project and the changes will imediately be reflected in the second project that depends on the first one. This makes development much easier than generating a new JAR file from that project every time something changes.